Ubuntu 22.04 doesn't detect bluetoth LE device
I have a mouse Logitech MX Vertical and, when I'm trying to detect it, I have no results. I've tried it on the same device in windows (dualboot) and it connected correctly. I've tried:

usual Bluetooth pairing
solaar
sudo modprobe -r btusb && sudo modprobe btusb
bluetoothctl and bluetoothctl scan le (returns empty list)
changing ControllerMode in /etc/bluetooth/main.con
Bluetooth manager

$ sudo dmesg | grep -i 'blue'
[  747.750051] Bluetooth: hci0: Firmware timestamp 2022.51 buildtype 1 build 56683
[  747.753765] Bluetooth: hci0: Found device firmware: intel/ibt-1040-4150.sfi
[  747.753810] Bluetooth: hci0: Boot Address: 0x100800
[  747.753814] Bluetooth: hci0: Firmware Version: 107-51.22
[  747.753819] Bluetooth: hci0: Firmware already loaded
[  747.826208] Bluetooth: MGMT ver 1.22
[  781.728269] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x2042 tx timeout
[  781.728346] Bluetooth: hci0: Opcode 0x2042 failed: -110
[  781.728365] Bluetooth: hci0: Unable to disable scanning: -110
[ 1293.117192] Bluetooth: hci0: Opcode 0x2042 failed: -110
[ 1293.117220] Bluetooth: hci0: Unable to disable scanning: -110
[ 1293.117254] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x2042 tx timeout
[ 1295.137188] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x2042 tx timeout
[ 1295.137193] Bluetooth: hci0: Opcode 0x2042 failed: -110
[ 1295.137217] Bluetooth: hci0: Unable to disable scanning: -110
[ 1295.137224] Bluetooth: hci0: stop background scanning failed: -110
[ 1326.141315] Bluetooth: hci0: Opcode 0x2042 failed: -110
[ 1326.141323] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x2042 tx timeout
[ 1326.141345] Bluetooth: hci0: Unable to disable scanning: -110
[ 1639.227334] Bluetooth: hci0: Opcode 0x2042 failed: -110
[ 1639.227351] Bluetooth: hci0: Unable to disable scanning: -110
[ 1639.227349] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x2042 tx timeout
[ 1639.227375] Bluetooth: hci0: Resetting usb device.
[ 1639.227685] Bluetooth: hci0: urb 000000007ce0992d failed to resubmit (2)
[ 1641.243335] Bluetooth: hci0: Opcode 0x2042 failed: -110
[ 1641.243358] Bluetooth: hci0: Unable to disable scanning: -110
[ 1641.243367] Bluetooth: hci0: stop background scanning failed: -110
[ 1641.243388] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x2042 tx timeout
[ 1641.243398] Bluetooth: hci0: Resetting usb device.
[ 1643.547386] Bluetooth: hci0: Reading Intel version command failed (-110)
[ 1643.827067] Bluetooth: hci0: Firmware timestamp 2022.51 buildtype 1 build 56683
[ 1643.830312] Bluetooth: hci0: Found device firmware: intel/ibt-1040-4150.sfi
[ 1643.830371] Bluetooth: hci0: Boot Address: 0x100800
[ 1643.830376] Bluetooth: hci0: Firmware Version: 107-51.22
[ 1643.830381] Bluetooth: hci0: Firmware already loaded
[ 1643.899030] Bluetooth: MGMT ver 1.22
[ 1745.209983] Bluetooth: hci0: Opcode 0x2042 failed: -110
[ 1745.210005] Bluetooth: hci0: Unable to disable scanning: -110
[ 1745.213931] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x2042 tx timeout

